# How to access 'this'.method in an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I have the following code:

```
function MyFunction () {
   this.my_method1 = function () {};
   this.my_method2 = function () {};
}
```

How can I access this.my_method1 in this.my_method2. I have tried using:

- this.my_method1()
- MyFunction.my_method1()
- my_method1()

but none seem to work. Help?

Comment: this.my_method1() is at least syntactically ok. the others are not. if you want more help, you'll need to define "not work"

Comment: I am trying to use it like this in my_method2: var b = this.my_method1(); Is this even possible?

Comment: it depends on how my_method2 is called. In order to understand `this`, you may want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MyFunction` function is basically a constructor. Therefore, to access methods you need to create an object out of it:

```
var foo = new MyFunction();
foo.my_method1();
foo.my_method2();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.